# Update attribute of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a User parent model and it's child model Comment. I want update to the profile_rating attribute of User whenever a comment is created. I am trying to use callback and I have added a method in comment class. I keep getting the error 'profile_rating is undefined' What am i doing wrong?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :comments,
     dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

  #update profile rating 
  after_save :update_profile_rating

  def update_profile_rating
     @new_profile_rating = user.profile_rating + 1
     User.update(user.profile_rating:  @new_profile_rating)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
def update_profile_rating
   @new_profile_rating = user.profile_rating + 1
   User.update(user.profile_rating: @new_profile_rating)
end
```

to:

```
def update_profile_rating
   @new_profile_rating = user.profile_rating + 1
   user.update(profile_rating: @new_profile_rating)
end
```

or:

```
def update_profile_rating
   user.update(profile_rating: user.profile_rating + 1)
end
```

or:

```
def update_profile_rating
   user.increment!(:profile_rating)
end
```

Comment: They should all work. Give them a try. Also, feel free to upvote/accept for future searchers.

Comment: @jvillian is it not should be `after_create :update_profile_rating` instead of `after_save`?

Comment: @Gabbar - Welp, I don't know. The OP specifies `after_save`. That may or may not be the correct behavior. Hard to say/know given the question as posed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def update_profile_rating
   user.update!(profile_rating: user.profile_rating + 1)
 end
```

Make sure that the default value of `profile_rating` is `0` in the migrations.

Comment: How do I set it to 0?

Comment: `t.integer :profile_rating, default: 0` in your migration in which User table is being created. Make sure to rollback and then rerun the migration again.